# There is a div I made contains the number of 8

Tags: function, setinterval, let, clearinterval

I'd like to make a countdown to make this number decrease to reach 0 and then stops, I tried to made this by setInterval, but it doesn't work I don't where the problem is because there's no error

let divv = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1]

function countdown() {
divv.innerHtml -= 1;

if (divv.innerHtml === "0") {
clearInterval(counte)
}

}

let counte = setInterval(countdown, 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with the errors corrected.

```
let divv = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];

function countdown() {
  divv.innerHTML = parseInt(divv.innerHTML) - 1;

  if (parseInt(divv.innerHTML) === 0) {
    clearInterval(counte);
  }
}

let counte = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

1. `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML`.
2. `innerHTML` returns a string, so you'd have to wrap it in parseInt, which tells the code that the value returned is a number, this is so you can decrement it.
3. After the parseInt step the if statement changes to compare to 0, not "0".

Comment: I can't express thanks to you